# RealTime DataBase Sorting a list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve a list of data ordered by a value

in my services

```
getsalesarea()
{
 return this.zonesalesList = this.firebase.list ('zonesales');
}
```

in my componet

```
  ngOnInit() {
    return this.zsalesService.getsalesarea()
    .snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.zsalesList = [];
    item.forEach(element => {
      let x = element.payload.toJSON();
      x["$key"] = element.key;
      this.zsalesList.push(x as Zsales);
    });
    });
  }
```

Data Base

```
areasales
  -MIqXQgh33O9X6W04NA5kwp
    description: "Alaska"
    id: "100"
  -MIqXZRwH1397p6TLbda_zJ
    description: "Hawaii"
    id: "101"
  -MIqXc_sPU560ssq18o5UoL
    description: "Kentucky"
    id: "102"
  -MPhs9ci338gXs_l34LsJc1
    description: " New Jersey, New"
    id: "103"
```

this code returns the list but it is not ordered.
How can I order the list by zone id?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

list = orderBy(list, 'id','asc'); use it when you retrive list.Might be some solution order while retrieving but if you want to achieve after you retrive, this is the way

Answer (score 0):

First things first

- always use const when you're not making another association

So, the correct here would like this:

```
const x = element.payload.toJSON()
```

- another thing is, name your variables with meaningful names

Instead of **x** you could use ***saleZone***

And the solution could be achieve with the following:

```
this.zSalesList = item.map(element => 
  ({
     ...element.payload.toJSON(),
     $key: element.key,
  })
)
.sort((a, b) => a.$key - b.$key) // here you can sort by the $key or id or another variable
```